# Codeigniter Glob Path

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a function in codeigniter with `glob apppath` but its got a couple of bugs unsure of.

On my permissions I am trying to get it to ignore some controllers that are set in my ignore array but still shows them up. And also says `controllers/header` where it should just say `header`

```
$ignore = array(
'footer',
'header'
);

$data['permissions'] = array();

$files = glob(APPPATH . 'controllers/*.php');

foreach ($files as $file) {
$part = explode('/', dirname($file));

$permission = end($part) . '/' . basename($file, '.php');

if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
$data['permissions'][] = $permission;
}
}

if (!empty($this->input->get_post('permission','access'))) {
$data['access'] = $this->input->get_post('permission','access');
} elseif (!empty($user_group_info['permission']['access'])) {
$data['access'] = $user_group_info['permission']['access'];
} else { 
$data['access'] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should use

```
          $permission = basename($file, '.php');
```

in place of
              $permission = end($part) . '/' . basename($file, '.php');

Comment: Also just checking if you think I have my if (!empty area done correct at bottom.